# jQuery :visible does not find the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I have an `text input` at certain screen sizes which changes to a `select` at other screen sizes.

**THE CHALLENGE**

I want to be able to get the value of the `input` or `select` on `keyup` or `change` without having to duplicate the code - so I give the elements the same ID, knowing they will never be visible at the same time, and choose to find the element using: e.g. `#ID:visible` - code below

```js
$('#test:visible').on('keyup change', function(){
 alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none">
 <input id="test">
</div>
<select id="test">
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

This simply doesn't work. [I have read the jQuery visible-selector page](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and it seems that I'm doing things the right way, but the alert simply does not fire.

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: However you can give a class and try it out

Comment: IDs are singular.... That is your issue

Comment: Even though they are not visible, elements with a 'visibility: hidden' still take up space on the DOM. Therefore you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> so I give the elements the same ID, knowing they will never be visible at the same time

Unfortunately, that's not how it works. You can't duplicate `id` attributes within the scope of the same document regardless of the elements being visible or not. You need to use classes to group multiple elements together:

```js
$('.test:visible').on('keyup change', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none">
    <input class="test">
</div>
<select class="test">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hmmm - yeah, just changed them to classes and all works ok - you live and learn! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.